# Renaming multiple files in one line of shell

Tags: bash, shell

## Problem

In a directory there are files of the format: *-foo-bar.txt.

Example directory:

```
$ ls *-*
asdf-foo-bar.txt  ghjk-foo-bar.txt  l-foo-bar.txt     tyui-foo-bar.txt
bnm-foo-bar.txt   iop-foo-bar.txt   qwer-foo-bar.txt  zxcv-foo-bar.txt
```

Desired directory:

```
$ ls *.txt
asdf.txt  bnm.txt  ghjk.txt  iop.txt  l.txt  qwer.txt  tyui.txt  zxcv.txt
```

## Solution 1

The first solution that came to my mind looks somewhat like this ugly hack:

```
ls *-* | cut -d- -f1 | sed 's/.*/mv "\0-foo-bar.txt" "\0.txt"/' > rename.sh && sh rename.sh
```

The above solution creates a script, on the fly, to rename the files. This solution also tries to parse the output of `ls` which is not a good thing to do as per http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

## Solution 2

This problem can be solved more elegantly with a shell script like this:

```
for i in *-*
do
    mv "$i" "`echo $i | cut -f1 -d-`.txt"
done
```

The above solution uses a loop to rename the files.

## Question

Is there a way to solve this problem in a single line such that we do not have to explicitly script a loop, or generate a script, or invoke a new or the current shell (i.e. avoid sh, bash, ., etc. commands)?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but -- note that `$(echo $i | cut -f1 -d-).txt` can be written a bit more Bashfully as `${i%%-*}.txt`. Also, if you're worried that parsing `ls` is not a good thing to do, then you should also be making better use of double-quotes: `mv "$i" "${i%%-*}.txt"`.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a loop? In this case, a loop could be more efficient because everything (apart from `mv`) could be done by the shell instead of invoking external commands like `find`, `sed`, `cut` etc.

Comment: @ruakh Thank you for your comment. In the original post, I specified that there are no whitespaces in the filenames. Hence, my sloppy usage of double-quotes. However, now I have updated my post now to remove that constraint, in favour of a more general solution. Thanks for the `${i%%-*}.txt` tip.

Comment: @SusamPal: I did notice your statement that there's no whitespace; but then, double-quotes also prevent interpretation of shell metacharacters like `*` and `?` and `[`. (If `$foo` is set to `*`, then `echo "$foo"` will print an asterisk, while `echo $foo` will print a list of the files in the current directory.)

Comment: A pipeline of external commands is more expensive than a native shell loop. But no matter what you use, you will have to invoke `mv` repeatedly because `mv` can only rename one file at a time. That is essentially what `xargs` is doing in Tim's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command?

For example:

```
rename 's/-foo-bar//' *-foo-bar.txt
```

If you don't have that available, I would use `find`, `sed`, and `xargs`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*-foo-bar.txt' | sed 's/-foo-bar.txt//' | xargs -I{} mv {}-foo-bar.txt {}.txt
```

Comment: Larry Wall `prename` is downloadable as a perl script runnable as user. http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.06/rename.PL

Comment: Or just `for file in *-foo-bar.txt; do echo "mv '$file' '${file%-foo-bar.txt}.txt'" ; done | sh` but that will break if you have file names with single quotes in their name.